# Python search for single filename recursively in directory tree. Return false if not found

Tags: python, recursion, filenames, os.walk

Using Python, I would like to search a directory tree recursively for a specific file name.

**If found, print nothing.

**If not found print a message stating it was not found.

===== here is what I have so far, no errors, but no message when file not found either=====

```
import os
rootDir = 'G:\\some_top_directory\\'
file_name = 'fileOFinterest.txt'
def find_file(file_name,rootDir):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootDir):
        if file_name in filenames:
            print 'found'
```

Answer (score 1):

Return early when you find the file; that way, after your `os.walk()` loop has completed you know the file was never found:

```
import os

def find_file(name, root):
    for _, _, filenames in os.walk(root):
        if name in filenames:
            return  # found the file, exit early
    print 'Not found'

rootDir = 'G:\\some_top_directory\\'
file_name = 'fileOFinterest.txt'
find_file(file_name, rootDir)
```

I used `_` for both the dirpath and directories values returned by `os.walk()` for each iteration; the loop otherwise ignores these and `_` signals this to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

```
if not any(file_name in filenames
           for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootDir)):
    print file_name, 'not found'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python3.5+ you can use `**` with the `recursive` flag:

```
import glob
rootDir = 'G:\\some_top_directory\\'
file_name = 'fileOFinterest.txt'
found_files = glob.glob("{}**\\{}".format(rootDir, file_name), recursive=True)
if not found_files:
    # do whatever you need
    pass
else:
    print('found')
```

Comment: This would find multiple files (the search continues after the first file was found), and you didn't handle the actual requirement of printing when none were found.